# red5 not stream flv with codecId=7

Tags: red5

I need to stream flv by Red5. Some files (which have codecId=2) streaming very well. But other flv with have format avc and codecId=7 are not streaming... I have Red5 0.9.0 RC2.

Maybe I need to insert some jars?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you elaborate on what you've tried, or what your specific problems are? Your question is very vague, so try adding a little more information to help the people who can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 1.0 plays any of the flv codecs, I suggest that you use a newer build. http://red5.googlecode.com/